# every time I change my widget xml, I get runtime error in eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I try to edit my android widget xml.

everytime I change one property (drawable, gravity...)

The layout is marked as error

build runs OK, but the application doesn't run.

Eclipse says there are errors, but I see no in the error window/problem/log-cat[image]

`Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag 
 LinearLayout`

[image]

Comment: you should probably remove the xmlns attribute from the linear layout.

Comment: remove the xmlns and then clean and build. except for the root tag remove the xmlns for linearlayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xmlns means XML Namespace.

I think that this attribute should be only on the first element of the XML file, and that's why you get the error